# How can I accommodate for long computational times in d3.transition callbacks?

Tags: d3.js

Sometimes you need to do computational intensive work (needed by the transition) in transition "start" and "end" event callbacks that might take such a long time that when the transition starts (or when the next chained transition starts for "end" events), time has already passed beyond the transition start time, causing the transition to jump.

The problem can be seen below. Both the first and the second animated transition jumps from its start values directly to half-done.

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3-selection.v1.min.js"></script>
<!-- This script is d3-timer.min.js with https://github.com/d3/d3-timer/pull/28 that fixes https://github.com/d3/d3-timer/issues/27 -->
<script>!function(t,n){"object"==typeof exports&&"undefined"!=typeof module?n(exports):"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["exports"],n):n(t.d3=t.d3||{})}(this,function(t){"use strict";function n(){return h||(x(e),h=v.now()+y)}function e(){h=0}function o(){this._call=this._time=this._next=null}function i(t,n,e){var i=new o;return i.restart(t,n,e),i}function r(){n(),++_;for(var t,e=f;e;)(t=h-e._time)>=0&&e._call.call(null,t),e=e._next;--_}function u(){h=(d=v.now())+y,_=m=0;try{r()}finally{_=0,c(),h=0}}function l(){var t=v.now(),n=t-d;n>w&&(y-=n,d=t)}function c(){for(var t,n,e=f,o=1/0;e;)e._call?(o>e._time&&(o=e._time),t=e,e=e._next):(n=e._next,e._next=null,e=t?t._next=n:f=n);s=t,a(o)}function a(t){_||(m&&(m=clearTimeout(m)),t-h>24?(t<1/0&&(m=setTimeout(u,t-v.now()-y)),p&&(p=clearInterval(p))):(p||(d=v.now(),p=setInterval(l,w)),_=1,x(u)))}var f,s,_=0,m=0,p=0,w=1e3,d=0,h=0,y=0,v="object"==typeof performance&&performance.now?performance:Date,x="object"==typeof window&&window.requestAnimationFrame?window.requestAnimationFrame.bind(window):function(t){setTimeout(t,17)};o.prototype=i.prototype={constructor:o,restart:function(t,e,o){if("function"!=typeof t)throw new TypeError("callback is not a function");o=(null==o?n():+o)+(null==e?0:+e),this._next||s===this||(s?s._next=this:f=this,s=this),this._call=t,this._time=o,a()},stop:function(){this._call&&(this._call=null,this._time=1/0,a())}};t.now=n,t.timer=i,t.timerFlush=r,t.timeout=function(t,n,e){var i=new o;return n=null==n?0:+n,i.restart(function(e){i.stop(),t(e+n)},n,e),i},t.interval=function(t,e,i){var r=new o,u=e;return null==e?(r.restart(t,e,i),r):(e=+e,i=null==i?n():+i,r.restart(function n(o){o+=u,r.restart(n,u+=e,i),t(o)},e,i),r)},Object.defineProperty(t,"__esModule",{value:!0})});</script>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3-dispatch.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3-interpolate.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3-color.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3-ease.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3-transition.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3-scale.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3-zoom.v1.min.js"></script>
  <div style="text-align: center;"></div>
  <script>

var start = Date.now();

function elapsed() {
    return Date.now() - start;
}

function waste(time) {
    var t0 = Date.now();
    while (Date.now() - t0 < time)
        ;
}

var svg = d3.select("div").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 800)
    .attr("height", 500);
var g = svg.append("g");

var start1Waste = 2000;
var end1Waste = 2000;
var start2Waste = 0;
var end2Waste = 0;

g.selectAll("rect")
    .data([10, 100, 200])
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", d => d)
    .attr("height", d => d)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "black")

var rect = g.append("rect")
    .attr("width", 10)
    .attr("height", 10)
    .attr("fill", "#d62728")
  .transition()
    .delay(2000)
    .duration(4000)
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 100)
    .on("start", function () {
        console.log('Start event 1', elapsed() / 1000);
        waste(start1Waste);
        console.log('Start event 1 returning', elapsed() / 1000);
    })
    .on("end", function () {
        console.log('End event 1', elapsed() / 1000);
        waste(end1Waste);
        console.log('End event 1 returning', elapsed() / 1000);
    })
  .transition()
    .attr("width", 200)
    .attr("height", 200)
    .attr("fill", "#1f77b4")
    .on("start", function () {
        console.log('Start event 2', elapsed() / 1000);
        waste(start2Waste);
        console.log('Start event 2 returning', elapsed() / 1000);
    })
    .on("end", function () {
        console.log('End event 2', elapsed() / 1000);
        waste(end2Waste);
        console.log('End event 2 returning', elapsed() / 1000);
    })

</script>
```

---

Note: a [bug in d3-timer](https://github.com/d3/d3-timer/issues/27) that is [fixed](https://github.com/d3/d3-timer/pull/28),
but at the time of this writing not yet released, requires this example to use a non official d3-timer.min.js.

Comment: a) Do the computationally intensive task in a web worker. b) use SMIL instead to animate and the browser will automatically take care of all the timings and account for any lagging.

Comment: @RobertLongson a) I've thought of a web worker myself, but how could one be used in this example, given that the transition needs the results of the computation? b) Wouldn't using SMIL imply giving up the use of d3.transition? Or can they be combined?

Comment: @RobertLongson I've clarified that the computations are needed by the transition in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For "start" events, you can't. Do the computational intensive work **before** the transition is created, or if this is not possible, in a separate preceding transition, to which this transition is [chained](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/346f4d967650b27c0511).
- For "end" events, you can add a delay to the second transition that is equal to or larger than the computational time of the end event callback of the first transition. If you want this to work for clients slower than your own, make the delay even longer.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3-selection.v1.min.js"></script>
<!-- This script is d3-timer.min.js with https://github.com/d3/d3-timer/pull/28 that fixes https://github.com/d3/d3-timer/issues/27 -->
<script>!function(t,n){"object"==typeof exports&&"undefined"!=typeof module?n(exports):"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["exports"],n):n(t.d3=t.d3||{})}(this,function(t){"use strict";function n(){return h||(x(e),h=v.now()+y)}function e(){h=0}function o(){this._call=this._time=this._next=null}function i(t,n,e){var i=new o;return i.restart(t,n,e),i}function r(){n(),++_;for(var t,e=f;e;)(t=h-e._time)>=0&&e._call.call(null,t),e=e._next;--_}function u(){h=(d=v.now())+y,_=m=0;try{r()}finally{_=0,c(),h=0}}function l(){var t=v.now(),n=t-d;n>w&&(y-=n,d=t)}function c(){for(var t,n,e=f,o=1/0;e;)e._call?(o>e._time&&(o=e._time),t=e,e=e._next):(n=e._next,e._next=null,e=t?t._next=n:f=n);s=t,a(o)}function a(t){_||(m&&(m=clearTimeout(m)),t-h>24?(t<1/0&&(m=setTimeout(u,t-v.now()-y)),p&&(p=clearInterval(p))):(p||(d=v.now(),p=setInterval(l,w)),_=1,x(u)))}var f,s,_=0,m=0,p=0,w=1e3,d=0,h=0,y=0,v="object"==typeof performance&&performance.now?performance:Date,x="object"==typeof window&&window.requestAnimationFrame?window.requestAnimationFrame.bind(window):function(t){setTimeout(t,17)};o.prototype=i.prototype={constructor:o,restart:function(t,e,o){if("function"!=typeof t)throw new TypeError("callback is not a function");o=(null==o?n():+o)+(null==e?0:+e),this._next||s===this||(s?s._next=this:f=this,s=this),this._call=t,this._time=o,a()},stop:function(){this._call&&(this._call=null,this._time=1/0,a())}};t.now=n,t.timer=i,t.timerFlush=r,t.timeout=function(t,n,e){var i=new o;return n=null==n?0:+n,i.restart(function(e){i.stop(),t(e+n)},n,e),i},t.interval=function(t,e,i){var r=new o,u=e;return null==e?(r.restart(t,e,i),r):(e=+e,i=null==i?n():+i,r.restart(function n(o){o+=u,r.restart(n,u+=e,i),t(o)},e,i),r)},Object.defineProperty(t,"__esModule",{value:!0})});</script>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3-dispatch.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3-interpolate.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3-color.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3-ease.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3-transition.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3-scale.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3-zoom.v1.min.js"></script>
  <div style="text-align: center;"></div>
  <script>

var start = Date.now();

function elapsed() {
    return Date.now() - start;
}

function waste(time) {
    var t0 = Date.now();
    while (Date.now() - t0 < time)
        ;
}

var svg = d3.select("div").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 800)
    .attr("height", 500);
var g = svg.append("g");

var start1Waste = 0; // Can't compensate for wasted time at start
var end1Waste = 2000; // Can be compensated with delay in next transition
var start2Waste = 0; // Can't compensate for wasted time at start
var end2Waste = 0;


g.selectAll("rect")
    .data([10, 100, 200])
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", d => d)
    .attr("height", d => d)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
        
var rect = g.append("rect")
    .attr("width", 10)
    .attr("height", 10)
    .attr("fill", "#d62728")
  .transition()
    .delay(2000)
    .duration(4000)
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 100)
    .on("start", function () {
        console.log('Start event 1', elapsed() / 1000);
        waste(start1Waste);
        console.log('Start event 1 returning', elapsed() / 1000);
    })
    .on("end", function () {
        console.log('End event 1', elapsed() / 1000);
        waste(end1Waste);
        console.log('End event 1 returning', elapsed() / 1000);
    })
  .transition()
    .delay(end1Waste)
    .attr("width", 200)
    .attr("height", 200)
    .attr("fill", "#1f77b4")
    .on("start", function () {
        console.log('Start event 2', elapsed() / 1000);
        waste(start2Waste);
        console.log('Start event 2 returning', elapsed() / 1000);
    })
    .on("end", function () {
        console.log('End event 2', elapsed() / 1000);
        waste(end2Waste);
        console.log('End event 2 returning', elapsed() / 1000);
    })

</script>
```

Comment: I'm very interested to see if someone has a better solution.